# Customize dropdownbutton - going up

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

It's maybe a stupid question, but I don't know how to make a dropdownbutton that go up and no down when it is focused.

Maybe I need to create my own ? Or is it possible to use dropdownbutton widget ?

Answer (score 0):

Use DropDownButton2 for the desired output, in which menu items are by default goes down,

[image]

Code goes like:

```
String? selectedValue;
List<String> items = [
  'Item1',
  'Item2',
  'Item3',
  'Item4',
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton2(
          hint: Text(
            'Select Item',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
              color: Theme
                      .of(context)
                      .hintColor,
            ),
          ),
          items: items
                  .map((item) =>
                  DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: item,
                    child: Text(
                      item,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
                  .toList(),
          value: selectedValue,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedValue = value as String;
            });
          },
          buttonHeight: 40,
          buttonWidth: 140,
          itemHeight: 40,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

For more examples and reference use the follwing link : [enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2)